# The method 'addSystemCategories' was called on null. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Why does this method call crashes in this error? I just want to add some data in my database when the switch is toggled.

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> The method 'addSystemCategories' was called on null. Receiver: null
> Tried calling: addSystemCategories()

```
void toggleCategoriesSupport () {
    CategoriesProvider categoriesProvider;
    categoriesProvider.addSystemCategories();
    _categoriesSupport = !_categoriesSupport;
    _saveToPreferences();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This is the method I call:

```
void addSystemCategories() {
    final categoryAll = ProductCategory(createdTime: DateTime.now(), id: '0', title: 'Alle', type: 'category');
    final categoryNothing = ProductCategory(createdTime: DateTime.now(), id: '1', title: 'Keine', type: 'category');
    addCategory(categoryAll);
    addCategory(categoryNothing);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `toggleCategoriesSupport` you wrote: `CategoriesProvider categoriesProvider;`. You declared `categoriesProvider` but you didn't assign it a value, so it has the value `null` by default. You probably meant to say `CategoriesProvider categoriesProvider = CategoriesProvider();`.